# How to include python==3 with virtual environment of python module

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am creating python bundle for a client. I want to add `python==3.7` also with that bundle so the user need not to install python on windows platform.

Created Virtual environment and copied that to new pc (without python install) and opened python from `venv/Script/Python.exe`.
But got error of missing dll files

I expect a bat file containing `python.exe` address from `venv` folder and running python file using `venv python.exe` or something like this

Comment: Welcome, Darshan to our community:) Check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453458/how-to-use-pyinstaller
IF you created an exe using pyinstaller it will include by default the python version with the needed packages so that the client will not need to install any additions on his PC to use your exe.