# How do I load a pickle model when using cx_freeze?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, setuptools, cx-freeze

My script, built as an application, stops working when it tries to load pickle model data. The following is the problematic code:

```py
with open('model_pickle','rb') as f:
    mp = pickle.load(f)
```

This is the setup file I’m using:

```py
setup(
    name="Test",
    version="1.0",
    options={"build_exe":{"include_files":["model_pickle"]}},
    executables=[target]
)
```

The program works as it should when executing the python script. However, after converting it to an executable via `cx_freeze`, the issue is with opening the pickle model data file. I have tested this with and without the data, so I’m pretty sure this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested your program with the IDLE ? Maybe there is a `pickle` decoding error... If not, try using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62023593/error-compiling-with-pyinstaller-error-loading-python38-dll/62081732#62081732) for creating your exe. It imports all the libraries that you have on your computer. It's longer, but easier: just one file to run.

---

Anyways, better user [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) (also a module available on PyPI) - [Related Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34453458#34454262)

Answer (score 1):

You can import model as follows `model = pickle.load(open('MODEL_PATH','rb'))` .Hope this will work!

Answer (score 1):

I’m 99.99% positive that you need to also add the `model_pickle` file to your `setup(…)` call as package data for this to work as an executable. Here’s a `setup.py` snippet showing the package data options:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

PROJECT_NAME = 'my_project' # this should reflect your package structure

setup(
    # …
    packages=[package for package in find_packages() \
                       if package.startswith(PROJECT_NAME)],

    package_dir={ 'my_project' : 'my_project' },
    package_data={ '' : ['*.*'] },
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=True,
    # …
)
```

Also, if I were you, I’d rename the data file to something like `model_pickle.pkl` so that your `package_data` expression doesn’t have to be double-wildcarded (as above).

If that doesn’t immediately work, I would also recommend [adding a `MANIFEST.in` file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) that explicitly names your binary data file.