# Unable to open .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I wrote a python script for a calculator and tried to convert my `.py` file to a `.exe` file. After converting to `.exe` file, I am getting `error("Failed to execute script <Filename>")`.

The solutions i have tried:

- I tried to run my python3.8 script using 3.6 script.
- I tried converting my .png icon to .ico image.
- I tried to convert my .py file .exe file using pyinstaller & auto-py-to-exe as well.

Comment: Does the script work if ran directly?

Comment: Try to convert onefile format

Comment: Try to use `cx_Freeze` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62023593/error-compiling-with-pyinstaller-error-loading-python38-dll/62081732#62081732